# Open Outlook with attachment from Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, outlook, office-interop

I have an Azure Hosted Web App. I need to add a button that when clicked, launches a new email window in outlook on the end user's machine with a prepopulated attachment.

I have tried using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library to achieve this. It works absolutely fine in a local debug environment however I have later learned it is not supported by Microsoft Azure.

Can anybody recommend an alternative solution going forward?

Comment: Where does the prepopulated attachment come from?

Comment: PDF generated in the app

Comment: So it needs to be downloaded to the user’s desktop, and then added to a new email on their machine in draft ready for them to add recipients/more info and then click send?

Comment: They don't want the hassle of going in to downloads, opening files and attaching them etc. They just want a button that opens a new email in Outlook that already has the PDF attached. Similar to mailto: functionality but with an attachment

Comment: You could integrate with the user’s exchange mailbox using EWS and create the draft for them with the attachment. But that’s pretty hard-hitting, not least because your app will need permissions to their mailbox and you’ll need to handle oauth. And they’ll still need to find the draft in outlook and send it

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to accomplish something similar, but none of them are the exact method you describe. Either one would involve sending a message from your backend as opposed to doing it from their local machine.

1) Instead of trying to create a new email on their account, have the system send them an email with the docs attatched that they could then forward with the attachements. It doesn't stop them from having to open up Outlook, but it does keep them from having to attach the files themselves.

2) Build on sasfrog's idea and but instead of putting it in the drafts folder, have them build out the entire email from your app and send it directly from there. It is probably the easiest from a user perspective as they never leave the page, but it would be a significant dev  effort.